# If input exists from one table update it on another one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Im trying to make like a refill code that will refill my table.
I have one table that have my refill code in it and other table that stores the balance of the account.

- table1: card_credit (table that stores the balance of the account)
  [image]
- table2:card_refill (table that have me refill code)
  [image]

I have created this code with session and PHP. Now I'm stuck and dont know how to move forward.

I want to make when i write in the refill code from table `card_refill` that its take the amount of `credit` into `value` in table `card_refill`

refill.php

```
 <strong>Refill</strong>
    <form action="refill.php" method"post">
    <input type="text" name="refillcode"/>
        <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Refill" />
    </form>

    <?php 

     // starting the session
     session_start();


     if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
     $_SESSION['refillcode'] = $_POST['refillcode'];
     } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Please post more code or information

Comment: Note: `session_start()` should be called before ANY output in the output buffer, so move it to the very top of the file, where there is no HTML or any other output.

Comment: You have also a typo here: `method"post"` a missing `=` sign.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, I am just don't know, where the `card_id` comes from.
This is inserting a new record into your `card_credit` table.

```
// starting the session before any output
session_start();
//include here the database connection file!
//for example:
//include('db_connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    //First do a  validation here, is the refillcode number, exists, etc...
    //Insert it into the table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO card_credit (card_id, value) VALUES ('[YOUR_CARD_ID_HERE]', " . intval($_POST['refillcode']) . ")";
    //Link is the resource variable when you created the mysqli_connect
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    //Redirect here if you want
}
?>
<!-- HTML CODE STARTS HERE -->
<strong>Refill</strong>
<form action="refill.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="refillcode"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Refill" />
</form>
```

Comment: That looks good. `card_id` comes from the table that stores the RFID card ID's. In another php page i have a session that stores the ID's of my cards. How do i put it in `[YOUR_CARD_ID_HERE]` like `$_SESSION['card']`?

Comment: @Kajmac With concatenate: `$sql = "INSERT INTO card_credit (card_id, value) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION["card"] . "', " . intval($_POST['refillcode']) . ")";`